Multiple ASP.NET Core Web API instances runs only once
I have an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API hosted on two IIS applications (app-1 and app-2) under the Default Web Site on a Windows 11 server.
Both IIS applications point to the same physical path (inetpub\wwwroot\myapp) and each application has its own dedicated application pool (app1 and app2). The application pools have unique identities (app1svc and app2svc), both of which are members of the Administrators group.
In the Web API, I have an AppEvents class implementing IHostedService, with StartAsync and StopAsync methods to handle application start and stop events. In the Program.cs, I register the hosted service using builder.Services.AddHostedService().
When accessing http://localhost/app-1, the StartAsync method is triggered as expected. However, when accessing http://localhost/app-2, the StartAsync method does not execute. It seems that the application starts only once, despite both IIS apps pointing to the same physical directory.
I've tried changing the AspNetHostingModel from InProcess to OutOfProcess, but the behavior remains the same.
Is there a way to deploy multiple instances of the same web app, each running separately but pointing to the same physical directory, so that each instance correctly triggers its own StartAsync?

You do not need to use AddHostedService. The default template code should work fine

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.

        builder.Services.AddControllers();

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

        app.UseAuthorization();


        app.MapControllers();

        app.Run();
    }
}


I use builder.Services.AddHostedService() to register the StartAsync and StopAsync. Also removing the code line the problem remains.

Hi,
after several hours I've found the "real" problerm.
For monitoring I use NLog; the problem is that in the second "instance" of WebApi NLog does not write.
Thank you very much for your availability
